# Fastet way to create 2D list from two 1D list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists :

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C']
sex = ['M', 'F', 'M']
```

What is the best way with good performance to create a list like this from these two:

```
comb = [['A', 'M'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'M']]
```

Comment: You just `zip()` them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> name = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> sex = ['M', 'F', 'M']
>>> zip(name, sex)
[('A', 'M'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'M')]
```

If you want items to be lists, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) or list comprehension to convert them:

```
>>> map(list, zip(name, sex))
[['A', 'M'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'M']]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(name, sex)]
[['A', 'M'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'M']]
```

NOTE: If you are using Python 3.x, `zip`, `map` return an iterator instead of a list. To get a list pass the returned value to [`list` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
list(zip(name, sex))
```